# Binary Jedis - Create Pool

Tags: java, jedis

Working on Jedis.. Trying to create a pool for BinaryJedis.

I have used the below code snippet for creating jedis Connection Pool

```
jedisPool = new JedisPool(host, port)
```

Tried using the below code for creating BinaryJedis Connection

```
binaryJedis = new BinaryJedis(host, port)
```

Is it possible to create a connectionpool for binaryJedis like `JedisPool`.

Moreover, binaryJedis connection is not thread Safe.

Kindly help me to resolve this problem

Comment: Jedis are binary by default, aren't they? I mean there's the light sight of the force and the dark side. Nothing in between. - My first thought when reading the title ;)

Comment: I don't know that library but if there is no pool you could roll your own.  If  `BinaryJedis` is not threadsafe this would indicate that it holds some state so you'd have to be careful to clean up that state if you're reusing a connection.

Comment: @Thomas - Should I change the title

Comment: Resolved the issue..